# Converting daily data to monthly and get months last value in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have data consists of daily data that belongs to specific month and year like this
[image]

I want to convert all daily data to monthly data and I want to get the last value of that month as a return value of that monthly data
for example:

```
AccoutId,   Date,    Return

  1       2016-01   -4.1999  (Because this return value is last value of january 1/29/16)

  1       2016-02    0.19    (Same here last value of february 2/29/16)
and so on
```

I've looked some of topics about converting daily data to monthly data but the problem is that after converting daily data to monthly data, they take the mean() or sum() of that month as a return value. Conversely, I want the last return value of that month as the return value.

Comment: This is a standard pandas question, and has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can groupby `AccountId` and the Year-Month. Convert to datetime first and then format as Year-Month as follows: `df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')`. Then just use `last()`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.groupby(['AccountId', df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')])['Return'].last().reset_index()
df
```

Sample data:

```
In[1]:
   AccountId     Date  Return
0          1   1/7/16      15
1          1  1/29/16      10
2          1   2/1/16      25
3          1  2/15/16      20
4          1  2/28/16      30

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.groupby(['AccountId', df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')])['Return'].last().reset_index()
df

Out[1]: 
   AccountId     Date  Return
0          1  2016-01      10
1          1  2016-02      30
```

Comment: @RutkayKarabulak change `df` in my answer to whatever the name of your dataframe is. You should not be receiving that error. What is the name of your dataframe?

Comment: Oh okay I've done it right now i just made some typo that's it. Thank you so much David!